# How to get access to US credit report while living outside USA?

Tags: united-states, credit-report, credit-history, identity-theft

I lived in United States for over eight years late 2000/early 2010s. For some reasons I think my identity has been stolen in the US, so I would like to check my credit report. However, I have moved back to Canada, and I cannot seem to figure out how to access my credit report without a current US address.

Does anyone know how to access US credit report without a current US address?

Or any other ways to ascertain that my identity has not been stolen?

Answer (score 2):

Go to [annualcreditreport.com](http://www.annualcreditreport.com) and follow the instructions. If you cannot use the online version, it will fall back to mail-in option.